# Layout constraints not applicable for custom button class in IOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, constraints

Hi I am beginner to IOS development. I created one custom class which extends UIButton class. For button object I am applying this class. But when I tried to add constraints for my button it's not accepting those constraints.I am not adding those constraints in to my custom button class but I am adding in to IB. When I change my class of button to default UIButton class then it works fine. Am I doing some thing wrong. Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the custom class of uibuttom to your customclass of button in IB. your constraint will work definitely. [image]

Comment: HI Ravi I already change my class. But its not applying my constraints. If I change it to default one i.e. UIButton then it works fine. You have any idea why this is so ?

Comment: ok you should create button reference with your custom button class and add reference to you ib outlet button. make sure you have changed your ib button custom class.